# IBM SPSS Data Collection Professional Survey Activation Problem

Tags: spss, data-collection

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out here.

I need to activate a survey via spss data collection professional. But i'm getting error at the end of activation. 
Error;

Unable to merge questionnaire documents. 
The following error(s) occurred during the merge:  - FATAL,Failed to merge documents Unable to merge due to conflicts:  Q8 : Object exist in previous version with different DataType
This may have been caused by a variable which has changed it s question type

Could you please help me? What i need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the previous responses didn't actually *answer* your question, here's a way to fix your problem: rename Q8 in your original metadata, e.g. 'Q8_revised' (or better, a more descriptive name) using Professional. Activation will then not throw an error anymore. When exporting, you will get both variables in your output (if you export *all* versions).

Background: The reason your problem occurs is that after activating a questionnaire, respondents may have posted answers to questions, which would make analysis (to say the least) confusing if Q8 would exist with answers in different types. Data Collection will lock main question types: Categorical, Text, Long (integers), Double (decimals). You can, however, add or remove answer categories, numbers of allowed categorical answers and the permitted ranges/lengths for the other question types.

Finally, Data Collection will store the actual questionnaire (metadata) version used by each respondent so you will be able to always determine what was actually shown to the respondent when taking the survey, improving the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

IBM divested the SPSS Data Collection software effective October 31, 2015.

To receive Technical Support for Data Collection issues, please email
UNICOM Technical Support directly at: intelligence.support@unicomsi.com.

The UNICOM Customer Portal can be found at: https://support.unicomsi.com/.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but if you deployed once, you can't change any of the survey's question types: if you had, say, a categorical question named Q1, you can't change it into a loop or an open ended question; you must use a different question ID in that case (Q1_A or something else, but not Q1: Q1 is already defined as categorical type in the DB).